# String passing from JavaScript to Qt/C++ object

Tags: javascript, c++, string, qt, webkit

I'm stuck on a QtWebKit bridge issue on Windows and I ran out of
options. I don't have access to the exact code used but its something like below.

C++

```
class MyObject : QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QString data() const;
    void setData(QString);
    Q_PROPERTY(QString data READ data WRITE setData)
};
/* ... */
MyObject myObject;
frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myObject", &myObject);
```

JavaScript

```
function drop(e) {
    var url = e.dataTransfer.getData('url');
    //alert(url);   // Displays url correctly
    myObject.data = url;    // Assigns url to C++ object myObject
}
```

The alert box correctly displays the string value, e.g. 10.10.0.1.
The parameter on setData gives me the string "1". If I then view then memory at that address, I see the full url in memory (formatted as UTF-32 (4 bytes per character)), but whatever I try (toStdString, toAscii, utf16 - just to get sensible data) I do not seem to be able to get/use the whole string.

I event thought that maybe the debugger is playing a trick on me, so I pass the data to the method that actually needs this data (which also used a QString) it all might work - but sadly no.

Even if I make MyObject::setData Q_INVOKABLE and call setData directly I get the same
behaviour:

```
myObject.setData(url);  // Assigns url to C++ object myObject
```

If I just pass the data as literal, all DOES work correctly, like

```
myObject.setData('10.10.0.1');
```

or

```
myObject.data = '10.10.0.1';
```

I do not understand why passing a literal works but a variable not, the 'url' variable should be a string type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm partly there. String passing works as expected. However, the C++ object is embedded on a webpage and wraps an ActiveX (ActiveQt) object.
For this, I've seen some pages where you create a class that inherits from a QWebPage. There you have a createPlugins method that asks the QUiLoader to construct the widget for you (alternatively you use the Qt Metatype system). And my C++ object is registered.
When I use this custom WebPage on my WebView (using setPage), the strings are passed in wrongly. When I disable calling setPage, the strings passed correctly.

So string passing works (in some conditions).

I've created a new issue for this: [Qt Webkit bridge ActiveQt string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008064/qt-webkit-bridge-activeqt-string)